# SonarQube Java rule for checking debug/trace logging level

Tags: java, if-statement, logging, sonarqube, rules

I'm trying to write a customized java rule to check if the debug/trace log levels are enabled. If the log level check has been forgotten, the rule should report an issue.

```
import org.apache.juli.logging.Log;
import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory;

public class CheckDebugAndTraceLevel {
    
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CheckDebugAndTraceLevel.class);

    void foo()
    { 
        if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) 
        { 
            LOG.debug("some debug text.."); 
        } 
        LOG.debug("some debug text.."); // Noncompliant {{ check LOG.debug with an if statement}}
        
        if(LOG.isTraceEnabled()) 
        { 
            LOG.trace("some debug text.."); 
        } 
        LOG.trace("some text.."); // Noncompliant {{ check LOG.trace with an if statement}}
    } 
}
```

I tested my rule with loggers and recieved "Log.debug" and "Log.trace" from my example class. Still, I get an assertion error while executing jUnit test.

```
public class DebugAndTraceRule extends BaseTreeVisitor implements JavaFileScanner {

private JavaFileScannerContext context;
private boolean logFlag = false;

@Override
public void scanFile(JavaFileScannerContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    scan(context.getTree());
}

@Override
public void visitMethod(MethodTree tree) {
    super.visitMethod(tree);

    String logOption;
    for (StatementTree statement : tree.block().body()) {
        if (statement.is(Kind.EXPRESSION_STATEMENT)) {
            logOption = statement.firstToken().text() + ".";
            //System.out.println(statement);

            ExpressionStatementTreeImpl eStatement = (ExpressionStatementTreeImpl) statement;
            MethodInvocationTreeImpl methodInvoc = (MethodInvocationTreeImpl) eStatement.expression();
            MemberSelectExpressionTreeImpl memberSel = (MemberSelectExpressionTreeImpl) methodInvoc.methodSelect();
            logOption += memberSel.identifier();

            // check logOption
            if (logFlag && (logOption.equals("LOG.debug") || logOption.equals("LOG.trace"))) {
                //System.out.println(logOption + " - line:" + statement.firstToken().line());
                context.reportIssue(this, tree, "debug/trace levels of your logger must be enabled!");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void visitVariable(VariableTree tree) {
    super.visitVariable(tree);

    if (tree.type().symbolType().toString().equals("Log")) {
        logFlag = true;
    }
}
```

}

If someone could help me out, I would really appreciate it!

[image: AssertionError]

Comment: Frame challenge: why do you want this rule? It's rarely worthwhile to do this check, and it harms readability. Every time I've seen it, it's been a case of premature optimisation. Unless you're doing some expensive operation inside a loop that happens very many times I would argue that the readability hit massively exceeds the benefit of saving a few clock cycles.